# Perfect numbers 1 to n

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, perfect-numbers

Write an algorithm  that prints perfect numbers from 1 to n.  To determine if a number is perfect add up all the factors of the number that are less than the number. If the sum is equal to the number, it is perfect.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assign_6 {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int num,number,sum=0,factor;

        System.out.print("Enter Number");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        number=keyboard.nextInt();

        for (num=1;num<number;num++){
            for(factor=1;factor<number;factor++){
                if(num%factor==0){
                    sum= sum+factor;
                }
                if(sum==num){
                    System.out.println(sum);
                }
                sum=0;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Output: 24

Nothing prints out. Don't know whats wrong. Where am I going wrong? I can only use while, for, and else-if statements.

Comment: This sounds like a *perfect* situation to learn how to use a debugger ;-)

Comment: deleted my answer because I gave the answer instead of clues....  First, you need to make sure that your code is formatted properly.  When formatted properly, it's clear what the code is doing.

Comment: @user605989 you're comparing "sum==num" instead of "sum==number"

Comment: @Dave O he's doing that part correctly.  The program is supposed to print ALL the perfect numbers between 1 and n, inclusive.

Answer (score 5):

Print out the sum for every number (and not just when sum==number) and you'll be able to figure it out.

(Two clues: correct indentation helps find matching { } pairs quickly. And it pays to give your variables descriptive names.)

Comment: I tried that. Now it prints all the number less than the number I type in. It doesn't pick out the perfect numbers.

Comment: @user605989 It prints out a lot more numbers than it should though, doesn't it? And a lot of them are zeroes.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is the problem. I have tried indenting differently. I don't know if that was correct or not.

Comment: @user605989 Which means that there's something wrong with the loops, that `System.out.print` is in the wrong place. And the lots of zero sums are a clue to the `sum=0` line being in the wrong place too.

Comment: The corrected indentation clue was to help you identify where certain operations are occurring in your for-loop. Re-read Biziclop's comment he just gave and you'll see the hint about the large number of 0's being printed.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in your code:

1. The following code should use a less than or equal to comparison, otherwise, you miss the `n`, only do 1 to `(n-1)`

   ```
   for (num = 1;num < number;num++){
   ```

   It should be the following code.

   ```
   for (num = 1;num <= number;num++){
   ```
2. The following code is inside of `for(factor=1;...)`, but it should be outside of the loop. Otherwise, you actually check & clear sum, for each factor.

   ```
   if(sum==num){System.out.println(sum);} sum=0;}
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Trace through your program on paper. There is an issue with your sum variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy when you are starting out coding to confuse your loops, since in this homework you have 2 for loops and they do different things.  As a hint, the reason your program is not working is because you have misplaced stuff from one for loop to the other.

You are in the right direction, but make sure you are able to think about those for loops separately.  That is, what is the inner loop's intended purpose?  What is it actually doing?  What is the outer loop's intended purpose, and what is it actually doing?  It looks like in your inner loop you are trying to sum up factors for num.  Is it actually just summing up the factors, or are there some side effects/errors you overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will help you:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       int n = in.nextInt();
       for(int j=1; j<n; j++)
       {
           int counter = 0;
           for (int i = 1; i < j; i++)         
           {              
               if(j%i ==0)
               {
                   counter = counter + i;
               }
           }
           if(counter == j)
               System.out.println(j);//here you can print j or counter
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PerfectNumber {
public static void main(String args [])
{

    perfectNumber(6,200);
}

static void perfectNumber(int num1, int num2){

    int i; int j; int sum=0;

     for (i=num1;i<=num2;i++){
            for(j=1;j<=i/2;j++){
                if(i%j==0){
                    sum= sum+j;
                }

            }
            if(sum==i){
                System.out.println("The perfect number between two numbers: "+sum);
            } 
            sum=0;
        }


    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
    class PerfectNumber

{

public static void main(String[]args)
{
    System.out.println("Enter the number upto which you want to print the perfect number");
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=scan.nextInt();
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
            sum=sum+j;
        }
        if(sum==(2*i))  //checks for perfect number
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int start,end;
  cin>>start>>end;
  for(int j = start;j<=end;j++)
  {
    int div=0;
   for(int i =1;i<j;i++)
  {
    if(j%i == 0)
    {
      div = div+i;
    }
  }
    if(div==j)
    {
      cout<<j<<" ";
    }
  }
 return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Hello Shyam, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you give some explanation on your code and why you have put a solution for C or C++ when question is for Java ?